# How to avoid the case that Google Translate translates undesirable blocks of markdown documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, google-translate

I want create a tool to bulk translate many documents written in Markdown format using API of Google Translate with NodeJS.

For example, suppose I have a file called `ansible-document.en.md` that contains the following content.

````
At first, insert the following tasks.

<!-- more -->

```YAML
- name: Unlock sudo
lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers
    regexp: '{{ ansible_env.USER }} ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD: ALL'
    line: '{{ ansible_env.USER }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
    validate: visudo -cf %s
become: yes
```
````

Although omitted here, metadata in Frontmatter format is also included in the this document.

I want to create a file called `ansible-document.zh.md` from this document.
So, when I sent the document to the API of Google Translate via `google-translate-api` package, I received the following undesirable result.

````
首先，插入以下任务。

<！ - 更多 - >

```YAML
- 名称：解锁sudo
lineinfile：
    dest：/ etc / sudoers
    正则表达式：'{{ansible_env.USER}} ALL = \（ALL \）NOPASSWD：ALL'
    行：“{{ansible_env.USER}} ALL =（ALL）NOPASSWD：ALL'
    验证：visudo -cf％s
成为：是的
```
````

I thought 6 steps were necessary to solve this problem instead of tear my hair.

1. Decompose the document into blocks.
2. Acquire a pair of sentences and information of a block. For example, is the block a heading, a paragraph, a code block or others.
3. If the block is not a code block or Frontmatter's key, send the text to the API of Google Translate.
4. Overwrite sentences in that block with sentences received.
5. Construct again in Markdown format.
6. Save as new filename.

Among them, 1, 2, 4 and 5 feel particularly difficult.
Please let me know if there is a NodeJS library that satisfies these functions?

Also, if you have a better approach above, please let me know.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is different from the assumed approach, I solved and will report answer.

1. Convert Markdown **to HTML**.
2. Send it **as HTML** to Google Translate API.
3. Convert the received HTML to Markdown.

The code block is no longer destroyed by Google Translate!
However, there are some small problems.

1. When translating as HTML, consecutive whitespace including newline is converted into one space. The code block is no exception.
2. Similarly, a space is inserted between “<code>” and “<pre>”, which makes it impossible to recognize that it is a fence of the code block.

These problems were easier to solve than this question.
Just replace line feed and indentation using DOM and regular expressions.
e.g. “<br>” and “&nbsp;”.

Thank you for thinking the answer.